# How to handle missing value for gradient crosstab using Bokeh 0.10.0?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh, missing-data

I am new and is using Bokeh 0.10.0, following this [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery/unemployment.html).

I am introducing missing value in the pandas df by

```
# Swap a real numeric value to missing
data['Jan'][0] = np.nan
```

After the line

```
data = data.set_index('Year')
```

When it runs, it gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\Try2.py", line 36, in <module>
    color.append(colors[min(int(monthly_rate)-2, 8)])
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How can we tell Bokeh to skip that missing value?

Comment: I don't know if there's a bokeh-specific solution for skipping missing values. Would filling with nan values with 0 suffice or do you want the bokeh output_file to show nothing at all (like a white rectangle)? What do you want the output to look like or what do you want to happen? `int(np.nan)` returns a ValueError. I think you'll run into problems if you try to skip values in an arrays because array lengths will be mismatched.

Comment: I prefer the missing value not be 0 because there are real values of 0. It can be assigned with values out of the 0 and 1 range to separate itself from real values. The goal is to show missing a recognizable color or blank and allows a good range of color gradient for real values ranging from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options.

[Option 1] Do a replace on the pandas DataFrame `data` beforehand and handle the color assignment in the for loop:

```
data.replace([np.nan], -1, inplace=True)
for y in years:
    for m in months:
        month.append(m)
        year.append(y)
        monthly_rate = data[m][y]
        if monthly_rate == -1:
            color.append('#FFFFFF')
        rate.append(monthly_rate)
        color.append(colors[min(int(monthly_rate)-2, 8)])
```

[Option 2] Handle the `np.nan` in the for loop with an `if`.

```
for y in years:
    for m in months:
        month.append(m)
        year.append(y)
        monthly_rate = data[m][y]
        if np.isnan(monthly_rate):
            rate.append(-1)
            color.append('#FFFFFF')
        else:
            rate.append(monthly_rate)
            color.append(colors[min(int(monthly_rate)-2, 8)])
```

Notice I am assigning the color `#FFFFFF`, and the value of `-1` but you can change it to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, the if then statement is what I was thinking after giving it more thoughts. I managed to tweak the colors list and color.append to give what I needed, but will use your solution for more consistent results in the future.